# knife ec2 service chef-client won't start : Couldn't find home environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife

I am using knife-ec2 to spin up an instance and bootstrap the node. The instance is started just fine, and it's able to SSH in, but once it runs the chef-client init_service recipe it's dying out on this line

```
service 'chef-client' do
```

The command I am running

```
knife ec2 server create -I ami-c2a818aa -f t2.micro --subnet {{subnet}} --server-connect-attribute public_ip_address -i {{key.pem}} -r "role[webserver]"
```

This is my output, something about not being able to find a home environment, but my home exists.

```
0.0.0.0 Recipe: chef-client::init_service
0.0.0.0   * template[/etc/init.d/chef-client] action create (up to date)
0.0.0.0   * template[/etc/sysconfig/chef-client] action create (up to date)
0.0.0.0   * service[chef-client] action enable
0.0.0.0     - enable service service[chef-client]
0.0.0.0   * service[chef-client] action start
0.0.0.0     
0.0.0.0     ================================================================================
0.0.0.0     Error executing action `start` on resource 'service[chef-client]'
0.0.0.0     ================================================================================
0.0.0.0     
0.0.0.0     Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
0.0.0.0     ------------------------------------
0.0.0.0     Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
0.0.0.0     ---- Begin output of /sbin/service chef-client start ----
0.0.0.0     STDOUT: Starting chef-client: [FAILED]
0.0.0.0     STDERR: /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/util/path_helper.rb:199:in `home': couldn't find HOME environment -- expanding `~' (ArgumentError)
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/util/path_helper.rb:199:in `all_homes'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/util/path_helper.rb:161:in `home'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/service/macosx.rb:36:in `gather_plist_dirs'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/service/macosx.rb:40:in `<class:Macosx>'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/service/macosx.rb:27:in `<class:Service>'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/service/macosx.rb:26:in `<class:Provider>'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/service/macosx.rb:25:in `<class:Chef>'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/service/macosx.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/providers.rb:93:in `<top (required)>'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/bin/chef-client:23:in `<top (required)>'
0.0.0.0         from /usr/bin/chef-client:51:in `load'
0.0.0.0         from /usr/bin/chef-client:51:in `<main>'
0.0.0.0     ---- End output of /sbin/service chef-client start ----
0.0.0.0     Ran /sbin/service chef-client start returned 1
0.0.0.0     
0.0.0.0     Resource Declaration:
0.0.0.0     ---------------------
0.0.0.0     # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/chef-client/recipes/init_service.rb
0.0.0.0     
0.0.0.0      32: service 'chef-client' do
0.0.0.0      33:   supports :status => true, :restart => true
0.0.0.0      34:   action [:enable, :start]
0.0.0.0      35: end
0.0.0.0     
0.0.0.0     Compiled Resource:
0.0.0.0     ------------------
0.0.0.0     # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/chef-client/recipes/init_service.rb:32:in `from_file'
0.0.0.0     
0.0.0.0     service("chef-client") do
0.0.0.0       action [:enable, :start]
0.0.0.0       updated true
0.0.0.0       supports {:status=>true, :restart=>true}
0.0.0.0       retries 0
0.0.0.0       retry_delay 2
0.0.0.0       default_guard_interpreter :default
0.0.0.0       service_name "chef-client"
0.0.0.0       enabled true
0.0.0.0       pattern "chef-client"
0.0.0.0       declared_type :service
0.0.0.0       cookbook_name "chef-client"
0.0.0.0       recipe_name "init_service"
0.0.0.0     end
0.0.0.0     
0.0.0.0   * service[chef-client] action restart
0.0.0.0     
0.0.0.0     ================================================================================
0.0.0.0     Error executing action `restart` on resource 'service[chef-client]'
0.0.0.0     ================================================================================
0.0.0.0     
0.0.0.0     Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
0.0.0.0     ------------------------------------
0.0.0.0     Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
0.0.0.0     ---- Begin output of /sbin/service chef-client restart ----
0.0.0.0     STDOUT: Stopping chef-client: [FAILED]
0.0.0.0     Starting chef-client: [FAILED]
0.0.0.0     STDERR: /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/util/path_helper.rb:199:in `home': couldn't find HOME environment -- expanding `~' (ArgumentError)
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/util/path_helper.rb:199:in `all_homes'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/util/path_helper.rb:161:in `home'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/service/macosx.rb:36:in `gather_plist_dirs'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/service/macosx.rb:40:in `<class:Macosx>'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/service/macosx.rb:27:in `<class:Service>'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/service/macosx.rb:26:in `<class:Provider>'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/service/macosx.rb:25:in `<class:Chef>'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/service/macosx.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/providers.rb:93:in `<top (required)>'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
0.0.0.0         from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/bin/chef-client:23:in `<top (required)>'
0.0.0.0         from /usr/bin/chef-client:51:in `load'
0.0.0.0         from /usr/bin/chef-client:51:in `<main>'
0.0.0.0     ---- End output of /sbin/service chef-client restart ----
0.0.0.0     Ran /sbin/service chef-client restart returned 1
0.0.0.0     
0.0.0.0     Resource Declaration:
0.0.0.0     ---------------------
0.0.0.0     # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/chef-client/recipes/init_service.rb
0.0.0.0     
0.0.0.0      32: service 'chef-client' do
0.0.0.0      33:   supports :status => true, :restart => true
0.0.0.0      34:   action [:enable, :start]
0.0.0.0      35: end
0.0.0.0     
0.0.0.0     Compiled Resource:
0.0.0.0     ------------------
0.0.0.0     # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/chef-client/recipes/init_service.rb:32:in `from_file'
0.0.0.0     
0.0.0.0     service("chef-client") do
0.0.0.0       action [:enable, :start]
0.0.0.0       updated true
0.0.0.0       supports {:status=>true, :restart=>true}
0.0.0.0       retries 0
0.0.0.0       retry_delay 2
0.0.0.0       default_guard_interpreter :default
0.0.0.0       service_name "chef-client"
0.0.0.0       enabled true
0.0.0.0       pattern "chef-client"
0.0.0.0       declared_type :service
0.0.0.0       cookbook_name "chef-client"
0.0.0.0       recipe_name "init_service"
0.0.0.0     end
0.0.0.0
```

Comment: I am wondering if this is a recent bug since I ran into a similar error today -- but never before and can't remember changing anything significant. Google only finds another pastbin link also from today. Did you install the system today?

Comment: Just checked in the freenode #chef IRC channel and was told that this is a bug introduced in the new 12.2.0 client published today.  I am still confused why their installer still installs this broken version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/chef/chef/pull/3154 indicates that a new version was released Mar 27 to address this.